# Can you open a PHP file anywhere in the page?

Tags: php

This question is confusing me. Can you open a php file from anywhere in a .php file?
Ex:

```
// index.php
<?php 
include('functions.php');
// ...
?>
<body>
// ...
</body>
<footer>
// This is what I'm trying to do
<?php include_once('blog.php'); ?>
</footer>
```

Comment: Technically yes. What problem are you facing because of this?

Comment: So what is the problem, if you really are trying to include `blog.php`?

Comment: All the codes after this include just don't appear. But I don't get any error in console

Comment: What's the contents of `blog.php`? Have you checked the webserver's error logs to see if there are any problems in there?

Comment: @Marc-AndréTrahan: What console?  Are there errors in the PHP logs?

Comment: So what is the "result" of `blog.php`? Does it `return` or `echo` anything?

Comment: Is blog.php included only once or already on the top of `<footer>`?

Comment: blog.php only contains functions.  So after that include, I'm calling a functions that is define inside blog.php

Comment: try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ` this before the include? May be your error messages are not displayed.

Comment: Also try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to @robert's code.

Comment: if blog.php relies on headers for e.g. sessions, you will need to take advantage of output buffering so the code can function properly.

Comment: Thanks the error messages now appear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation says

> 'A PHP script can be placed anywhere in the document'

So since include('functions.php'); is a PHP script, it can be placed anywhere in the document.So yes, we can open a PHP file anywhere in the page.